Does the double improper integral convergence with singularity at $(b,d)$ in $[a,b) \times [c,d)$
I am studying the convergence of double improper integrals and came upon the comparison test for double improper integrals from the book Sudhir R. Ghorpade, Balmohan V. Limaye - A Course in Multivariable Calculus and Analysis. The comparison test is for unbounded subset $[a,\infty]\times [c, \infty]$ and a bounded function, but would it work also if the function is unbounded at point $(b,d)$ in a bounded area $[a,b)\times[c,d)$?
The theorem is as follows:
Comparison Test for Improper Double Integrals) 
Suppose $a, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f, g: [a, \infty) \times [c, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ are such that both $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $[a, x] \times [c, y]$ for every $(x, y) \geq (a, c)$ and $|f| \leq g$. If
\begin{equation}
    \iint_{[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)} g(s, t) \, d(s, t)
\end{equation}
is convergent, then
\begin{equation}
    \iint_{[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)} f(s, t) \, d(s, t)
\end{equation}
is absolutely convergent and
\begin{equation}
    \left| \iint_{[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)} f(s, t) \, d(s, t) \right| \leq \iint_{[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)} g(s, t) \, d(s, t).
\end{equation}
Proof For $(x, y) \in [a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)$, let $F(x, y) := \iint_{[a, x] \times [c, y]} f(s, t) \, d(s, t), G(x, y) := \iint_{[a, x] \times [c, y]} g(s, t) \, d(s, t)$
and $\tilde{F}(x, y) := \iint_{[a, x] \times [c, y]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t).$
Assume that $\iint_{[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)} g(s, t) \, d(s, t)$ is convergent. Then the function $G$ is bounded above. Since $|f| \leq g$, we see that $\tilde{F} \leq G$, and hence the function $\tilde{F}$ is bounded above. Also, since $|f| \geq 0$, it follows from Proposition 7.55 that
$
\iint_{[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t)
$
is convergent, that is,
$
    \iint_{[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)} f(s, t) \, d(s, t)
$
is absolutely convergent. Further, since $-f \leq |f| \leq g$ and $f \leq |f| \leq g$, we have $-F(x, y) \leq \tilde{F}(x, y) \leq G(x, y)$ and $F(x, y) \leq \tilde{F}(x, y) \leq G(x, y)$ for all $(x, y) \geq (a, c)$. Letting $(x, y) \to (\infty, \infty)$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\left| \iint_{[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)} f(s, t) \, d(s, t) \right| \leq \iint_{[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)} g(s, t) \, d(s, t),
\end{equation}
as desired.
$\square$

Please share your own attempts to answer your question (the answer is yes and the proof is essentially the same. Did you try?).

"The comparison test is for unbounded subset [a,∞]×[c,∞]
and a bounded function": where did you see "bounded"?
